# SonarLint for Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

Does anyone know if the sonar lint visual studio 2015 extension can be applied to visual studio 2017 RC?

Is there much difference between the two IDE's that affects the way the plugin works? Is it just adding the version to a manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of SonarLint for VisualStudio will only work with VS2015 because of some checks done and some major changes in VS2017. But we have just finished a sprint on enabling SonarLint for VS2017 and a RC should be released soon (most probably this week).

Comment: The final version was just released a couple of minutes ago. You can install it either from your Visual Studio or from our website: http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Extension loading, and some of the APIs changed in VS2017. So it's not just a matter of updating the manifests. However, we are working on the VS2017 support, and it should be available shortly.